# Word wrap in gtkmm GtkTreeView

Tags: word-wrap, gtkmm, gtktreeview

I'm writing a program using `gtkmm-2.4` GUI package in Linux. How can I set a text column of a TreeView object to perform word wrapping in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, the strange and delightful word of GTK's CellRenderers.

```cpp
#include <pangomm/layout.h>

// say we want to wrap the 3rd column in our treeview
int colNum = 3;
Gtk::CellRendererText* pCellRendererText = dynamic_cast<Gtk::CellRendererText*>(pTreeView->get_column_cell_renderer(colNum));
pCellRendererText->property_wrap_mode() = Pango::WRAP_WORD;
pCellRendererText->property_wrap_width() = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was reading the reference doc to figure out how to do that for a few hours...